# Using Dask distributed, how can a function introspect to know if it's running as a distributed future or as a "normal" function?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm using Dask Distributed to submit functions to my cluster with the `client.submit` interface. If a cluster is not available I default to serial, non-distributed, execution. I would like to be able, from the function, to determine if it's running as a distributed future or as a normal function.

For example, for the `work` function below I would like to know if it's running via `client.submit(work)` or simply as `work()`.

```
def work():
    if is_distributed():
       # do stuff
    else:
       # do different stuff
```

what should `is_distributed()` look like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the function `distributed.worker.get_worker`. It will either return worker instance, or raise a `ValueError`.
So you could do something like

```
def is_distributed()():
    import distributed.worker
    try:
        get_worker()
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```